# Documentation target starts generating "Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported"

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app I have a default Documentation target that's been there for a long time.

Today, out of the blue (it seems), it stops building with:

```
objc[3964]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.
/Users/case/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Talk-ghsjogqghrvpujdilbabqcornjqr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Talk.build/Debug-iphoneos/Documentation.build/Script-48338F031615E3F60033F4C1.sh: line 2:  3964 Abort trap: 6           /Applications/appledoc --verbose xcode $SOURCE_ROOT/$PROJECT_NAME
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 134
```

I tried Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder..., emptying the DerivedData directory, and restarting Xcode.

Any idea how to fix this rather annoying issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you may have an old copy of `appledoc` in your /Applications directory. I suspect you built it at some point, installed it, and never upgraded it. I suspect your copy is v2.0 (~2010), which had garbage collection turned on. Garbage collection has been deprecated for years, and was recently removed from the OS. The current version is 2.2.1 (released in 2015).

Upgrade [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc). My preferred way to handle those kinds of packages is with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

```
rm /Applications/appledoc
brew install appledoc
```